# How could I set 2 pictures at top left/right corners of the section without id or class attributes HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

// I am asked to create a web site without the ability of using ids or classes. They would like to put two pictures at the top of the section. I used two examples in the section html code for example. They will be small and up tight againts the Title - specifically when I use the img vertical-align -20 and section h1 margin top -130 in css.

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: -20px;
}
section {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    width: 1050px;
    height: 1400px;
    margin-top: -1190px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 140px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 2px black;
}
section h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px red;
    margin-top: -130px
}

<section>
    <img src="canada.png" alt="Canada" />
    <img src="canada.giff" alt="Canada" />
    <h1>Title</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: `margin-top: -1190px;` Seriously somethings wrong, and as far as answer goes, check out `nth-of-type` pseudo

Comment: the header is making the section margin top - because it is big.

Answer (score 2):

It 's easy simply write align="right/left" in the html code like this:

```
<img align="left" src="canada.png" alt="canada" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make atribute selectors on `src` like this:

```
img[src="canada.png"] { 
   /* Styles for canada.png */
} 

img[src="canada.gif"] { 
   /* Styles for canada.gif */
}
```